# Concatenate Year and Month

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 date fields, surv_year (int) and surv_month (text).

Example outputs:

```
surv_year surv_month
2022      January
2022      August
```

Is there anyway to concatenate the 2 and change the month from a text to a number and have my final output as YYYYMM with my example above showing 202201 and 202208?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the two values to a proper date using the `to_date()` function:

```
select to_date(concat(surv_month, ' ', surv_year), 'Month yyyy')
from the_table
```

will return a `date` on the first day of that month.

This date can be formatted using the `to_char()` function to the format that you want:

```
select to_char(to_date(concat(surv_month, ' ', surv_year), 'Month yyyy'), 'yyyymm')
from the_table
```

Comment: That's great, thank you. I don't suppose this could also be converted to an INT rather than TO_CHAR at all?

Comment: `to_char(....)::int`